# ruby on rails instance variable and if elsif

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, instance-variables

In my Show View I have:

```
  <div class="reviews" >
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= review_block review %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

In my Controller I have:

```
  def show    
  @review = Review.new
  @reviews = @user.reviews
  end
```

The idea is that if there are reviews that have been written,
they are displayed on the page underneath the divs that currently exist- this part is working ok.

But if there are no reviews written, I just get nothing underneath the currently existing divs. How could I display some text like 'No reviews written, sorry!'

Ideally I'd like to show a partial, because I will be displaying more texts/ images.

I was working on something like this:

```
  <div class="reviews" >
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= review_block review if review>0 %>
  <%= else render :partial => 'layouts/no_reviews' %>
  <% end %>
```

But it's not working. Thanks for any help!

Chris

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="reviews" >
<% if @reviews && @reviews.present? %>
  <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
  <%= review_block review %>
<% end %>
<%= else render :partial => 'layouts/no_reviews' %>
<% end %>
```

e.g.

```
1.9.3-p327 :012 > if @abc
1.9.3-p327 :013?>   puts 'yes'
1.9.3-p327 :014?>   end
 => nil # We get noting
1.9.3-p327 :015 > @abc='lolololo'
 => "lolololo" 
1.9.3-p327 :016 > if @abc
1.9.3-p327 :017?>   puts 'yes'
1.9.3-p327 :018?>   end
yes # We get yes
```

Comment: Wouldn't an empty array go through the if statement just like a non-empty array? You might want to use `<% if @reviews && @reviews.present? %>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div class="reviews" >
  <% if @reviews.any? %>
    <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
      <%= review_block review %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/no_reviews' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Works great. So easy when you see the code done out like that. Thanks also, Michael.

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to express your gratitude in the form of an up-vote (but only if you found the answer helpful).